# Facebook App Invites on iOS 9 with last FB iOS SDK zoomed out

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing an odd error using latest FB SDK with iOS9. The Invite Friends dialog, opened with App Invites, is very zoomed out, making really difficult to press the Next button. Please see the below screenshot.

Anyone faced the same problem and solved? Have a look at my code below.

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://angrygranny.com/"];
content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://angrygranny.com/img/promo.png"];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

Screenshots:
[image: First Zoomed Screen][image: Second Zoomed Screen][image: 100% Zoom]

Many thanks

Comment: You mention you use SDK 5. Do you mean the Facebook iOS SDK? The latest version of that is 4.4.0, right? Currently, iOS 9 is not yet public and also not (actively) supported in one of the SDKs.

Comment: Yes exactly Facebook IOS SDK 4.4.0. That 5 in the titles was a mistake. So you think that's some incompatibility with iOS9? That might be the reason I will check for new updates to the IOS SDK and see if they fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about iOS 9 support currently. Can you file a bug, at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs, and provide a small sample XCode project to reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Facebook on the Login team. We're aware of this issue and looking into a fix now.

Please report this at developers.facebook.com/bugs so you'll get updates on our progress to resolution.